# Boolean cast Specified cast is not valid error

Tags: c#, checkbox, casting

I am currently storing the true/false status of a checkbox.Checked value in the registry to reset the next time a form is loaded.

When the form is loaded I get the value and set the checkbox like this.

```
string value = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\AddressLoad", "SpaceBetween1", null);
if (value != null)
{
    if (value == "True")
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
    } Else {
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

This works but I feel there is probably a better way to do it.

I tried this

```
checkBox1.Checked = (Boolean)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\AddressLoad", "SpaceBetween1", null);
```

But it gives me a `"Specified cast is not valid."` error.

The value is being stored as REG_SZ in the registry. Not sure if that is causing he issue.

[image]

I have searched for how to resolve this but have not found a case where it has been done this way.

Is there a better way to cast a string value to boolean and assign it to a checkbox?

Comment: You can try to use `bool.Parse` but I think you get the same error. I'm not sure though.

Comment: @MatthewD read the MSDN documentation and try to understand what [Registery.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) Method does

Comment: Got it.  Thank you SO friends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the type of the value that you read from the registry is a `string`, you cannot cast it. However, you can [*convert*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd(v=vs.110).aspx) it:

```
checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(
    Registry.GetValue(
        @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\AddressLoad"
    ,   "SpaceBetween1"
    ,   null
    )
);
```

Comment: That is it. Thanks.  I'll accept this as the answer when it will allow me to.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Convert.ToBoolean`, since `Registry.GetValue` will return an `object` and if it is of type `bool` or if it contains string `true/false`, you will get the result.

For example:

```
object obj = "true";
bool b = (bool) obj; //This will fail
bool b2 = Convert.ToBoolean(obj); //This will work.
```

Comment: it's not going to return a bool: it will return a string (in this case) that you have to parse somehow as a bool.

Comment: @GianPaolo, to use `Parse`, you have to cast/convert it to string first. `Convert.ToBoolean` avoids that.

Comment: Convert.ToBoolean is a way to "somehow parse" the object returned from Registry.GetValue. the actual type returned can be a string, as in this case, or a numeric (int? long? I should check), but in any case will be bool
Convert.ToBoolean can handle the string

Comment: @GianPaolo, ummm are you asking that `Convert.ToBoolean` can handle the string values of `true/false` ? if so , then yes.

Comment: @GianPaolo not sure if you downvoted or not. but dont down vote unless you are 100% sure.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, I didn't downvote any comment/answer. 
I was not asking, I was saying that "true" "false" can be handled by Convert.ToBoolean, and this is a form of the parsing I was talking about. You have to parse/convert somehow GetValue() result since it will return a type based on the type on the registry entry, that in any case will be a bool

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `Convert.ToBoolean`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

[`REG_SZ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884(v=vs.85).aspx) is a `string`.

With that in mind you can do

```
checkBox1.Checked = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CompanyName\AddressLoad",
    "SpaceBetween1", null).ToString() == "True";
```